# I encounter some Devise errors when running Rails 5 and perform requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, webrick

When I check the Webrick logs I notice the following:

```
Started GET "/tags" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-30 08:16:58 +0000
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bundler/gems/rails-f7d0a3ba7e9e/actionpack/lib/action_controller/api.rb:110: warning: already initialized constant ActionController::API::MODULES
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bundler/gems/rails-f7d0a3ba7e9e/actionpack/lib/action_controller/api.rb:110: warning: previous definition of MODULES was here

ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `helper_method' for ActionController::API:Class):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bundler/gems/rails-f7d0a3ba7e9e/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bundler/gems/rails-f7d0a3ba7e9e/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (8.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bundler/gems/rails-f7d0a3ba7e9e/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bundler/gems/rails-f7d0a3ba7e9e/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bundler/gems/rails-f7d0a3ba7e9e/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (38.9ms)
```

I checked the following Github updates:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3690

But when I try to update as suggested:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21151

I cannot find the mentioned information in these files:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/fd2508522c341c3f708219b5fc1834f24caf04e3

Any ideas ? Thank you !

Comment: Apparently, this seems to solve the problem: https://github.com/posgarou/devise/commit/a3da40a701197961d8eae0ca0cf75300a85b7cf2

Answer (score 0):

i had that problem, i found some solution on git, i don't have the link, but here is it:

You need to add to `application_controller.rb` :

```
def self.helper_method(*); end
```

and if you have the same problem with `...undefined method 'helper'...` add this:

```
def self.helper(*); end
```

This solved my problem.
Its not the best solution in my opinion, but until devise will support rails 5 and they fix it in their side, that workaround works ...